# Missing fields in request to upload files to minio using the generated presigned url

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, minio

I'm using Minio Server to handle files in my nodejs API, basically to emulate s3 locally. I generated Presigned Url to upload images directly.

Presign Url Generation works fine but when I upload my file from Postman the file it gives me this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>MissingFields</Code>
    <Message>Missing fields in request.</Message>
    <Key>records/marbles.jpg</Key>
    <BucketName>bucket</BucketName>
    <Resource>/bucket/records/marbles.jpg</Resource>
    <RequestId>16E442AB40F8A81F</RequestId>
    <HostId>0149bd16-e056-4def-ba82-2e91346c807c</HostId>
</Error>
```

The request seems to contain the required headers [as mentioned in this thread](https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/6844):

[image]

the headers are:

[image]

and I also select the file properly in postman(`Body>binary>select file`) :

[image]

The code I use for presigned url generation is:

```
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner';
import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
const s3Client = new S3Client({
        region: 'us-east-1',
        credentials: {
        accessKeyId: 'minioadmin',
        secretAccessKey: 'minioadmin',
    },
        endpoint: http://172.21.0.2:9000,
        forcePathStyle: true,
    });
  
const bucketParams = {
        Bucket: 'myBucket',
        Key: `marbles.jpg`,
};  
  
const command = new PutObjectCommand(bucketParams);

const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, {
        expiresIn: 10000,
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying and changing ports, and the `put` command seems to work when I use only local host for url generation

so, in this above:

```
new S3Client({
        region: 'us-east-1',
        credentials: {
        accessKeyId: 'minioadmin',
        secretAccessKey: 'minioadmin',
    },
        endpoint: http://172.21.0.2:9000,
        forcePathStyle: true,
    });
```

I use:

```
new S3Client({
        region: 'us-east-1',
        credentials: {
        accessKeyId: 'minioadmin',
        secretAccessKey: 'minioadmin',
    },
        endpoint: http://172.21.0.2, // or 127.0.0.1
        forcePathStyle: true,
    });
```

Note, I haven't used any port number, so the default is `80`

If you're using `docker-compose` add this config:

```
. 
.
.
ports:  
  - 80:9000
```

and it works fine.

Comment: Changing the port did not work for me.

Comment: @Arman , note the endpoint